# Python: pop from empty list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I'm trying to write a simple program, it needs to sort numbers in one file and write the output to another one, but I'm not able to do it.

```
from sys import argv
try:
    with open(argv[1],"r") as desti:
        with open("nums_ordenats.txt","w") as prl:
            for n in desti:
                argv.pop(0)
                argv.sort()
                argv.sort(key=len)
            prl.write(str(n)+("\n"))
except Exception as err:
    print(err, "Error")
```

Can someone explain me where is the error? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is your input and what results did you get with your code?

Comment: My input is a file with numbers and result was the name of the title.

Comment: @Kiloni When someone asks for your input, they are asking for you to provide the actual data so that they can reproduce your error.

Comment: @SethMMorton I think I gived the ifnromation to reproduce the error. Sorry if it could have been interpreted differently. It's the first time what i posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach wasn't working because index goes out of range instead you could do the following code to read and sort the numbers present in the file.

```
from sys import argv    
with open(argv[1],'r') as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            print (sorted(map(int, line.split(','))))
```

If your file contains comma seperated values.

Comment: Thanks to all. In my file I had the numbers row by row, and I change separate with comma. Now it's works.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the line `argv.pop(0)`, because `argv` is empty when it runs. This means that `desti` (`argv[1]`) is longer than `argv`.
The reason for this is that argv is in the format `['C:\\This\\is\\a\\path.py']` and so contains only `'C:\\This\\is\\a\\path.py'`. `argv[1]`,
 however(`'C:\\This\\is\\a\\path.py'`) contains each individual character, because it is a string. If you want each individual folder(and then the file), you can use:
`argv[1].split('\\')`, which will return: 
`['C:', 'This', 'is', 'a', 'path.py']`